# Cambodia E-visa: new SAI airport missing from entry port list, can I use REP?

Tags: airports, cambodia, siem-reap

The new SAI airport is missing from the list of airports at https://www.evisa.gov.kh/application

Can I apply with the now closed REP as the port of entry? I assume this has already happened to many travelers this week.

Comment: The Cambodia government application form linked in your question contains a port of entry listing for Siem Reap International Airport. Wikipedia tells me that airport code "SAI" is assigned to Siem Reap - Angkor International Airport. Isn't that where you're heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was there Dec 19th 2023, no problem in choosing Siem Reap international airport

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The form does not list REP or SAI. It just lists Siem Reap International Airport. And there's only one with that name now – as SAI, which added Angkor in its name, sure, replaced SRE.

You don't have too many choices if you are landing at Siem Reap...

Comment: Sure, but technically that is the name of the old REP airport https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siem_Reap_International_Airport

The new one is also sort of Siem Reap, but super technically it's not it, and border agents are not known worldwide for their flexibility on formal matters.

Comment: The new one is called Siem Reap Angkor International Airport, and is the only one being operated. You can throw all the technicalities you want at the screen, and waste your time, or go with the flow...

Comment: me I'm not throwing anything. I also don't wanna waste money or time at the border control.I am asking if anyone can confirm this experience. (there have been thousands of travelers already landing in the new airport)

Comment: "technically", "super technically" – yeah... Bottom line, there's only one airport in Siem Reap.